# Wordpress - remove query string parameter but leave value

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need some help with my Wordpress htaccess. I have a custom page (/offer) where I generate content from `&_GET['name']`. So my urls look like this:

```
https://mypage.com/offer/?name=product1
https://mypage.com/offer/?name=product2
```

What I want to do is:

```
https://mypage.com/offer/product1
https://mypage.com/offer/product2
```

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]*)\?name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

The Urls looks nice but there is an error 404.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^offer/$ /offer/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]+)/?$ /offer/?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?